# How to print the two for loop outputs in a single line (n1 and n2) in a single line

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

```
fhand=open(file)
n2=0
for line in fhand:
    if line .startswith("1/15/2014"):
        n2=n2+1
    print n2
n1=0
for line in fhand:
    n1=n1+1
    print n1
```

Comment: Note that, as written, the second `for line in fhand` will not do anything as the `fhand` iterator has already been exhausted.

Comment: @ jonrsharpe


fhand=open(file)
count=0
for line in fhand:


    count=count+1
print"The file has",count,"lines"



fhand=open(file)
count=0
for line in fhand:
    if line .startswith("1/15/2014"):
        count=count+1
print " of which",count,"are from 1/15/2014"

this is the code.(counting lines) I want both the print lines in a single line instead of using two print commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loops are so similar; just put the code for one inside the other:

```
for line in fhand:
    n1 += 1
    if line.startswith("1/15/2014"):
        n2 += 1
    print n2, n1
```

As danidee mentioned, you should always use `with` when opening files:

```
with open(file) as fhand:
    for line in fhand:
        n1 += 1
        if line.startswith("1/15/2014")
            n2 += 1
        print n2, n1
```

Comment: always remember to use `with` when opening files

Comment: Thank you ! but instead of counting the number of lines in the file, the program is just printing the lines.

Comment: You mean it is printing each line as it is read, but it does not display the line counts?